# Подключение к MySQL через JDBC на c Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, база-данных, jdbc

Возможно ли подключение с Android через JDBC к MySQL server без помощи php?

Comment: 10 секунд поиска дали результат: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12233178/1568530

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По какому протоколу вы хотите подключиться? Если HTTP, то вам не нужен JDBC непосредственно в Android, он должен быть на сервере куда вы подключаетесь. Если напрямую по TPC/IP, то следует понимать, что подключение мобильных устройств к сети нестабильно, связь может прерываться, обладать плохим качеством, низкой скоростью и пр. Как вы планируете решать эти проблемы? JDBC не рассчитан на подобные казусы. По-поводу вопроса - вам просто надо добавить JDBC библиотеку в свой проект.